# Finding zero values with odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I find the point where the first derivative of my equation equals 0 using scipy.integrate.ode?

I set up this function, which gets the answer, but I'm not sure about accuracy and it can't be the most efficient way to do this.

Basically I am using this function to find the time a projectile with initial velocity stops moving. With systems of ODEs, is there a better way to solve for this answer?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx=(np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx], idx

def deriv(x,t):
    # This function sets up the following relations
    # dx/dt = v , dv/dt = -(Cp/m)*(4+v^2)
    return np.array([ x[1], -(0.005/0.1) * (4+ (x[1]**2)) ])

def findzero(start, stop, v0):
    time = np.linspace(start, stop, 100000)
    #xinit are initial vaules of equation
    xinit = np.array([0.0,v0]) 
    x = integrate.odeint(deriv,xinit,time)
    # find nearest velocity value nearest to 0
    value, num = find_nearest(x[:,1],0.0001)
    print 'closest value ',
    print value
    print 'reaches zero at time ',
    print time[num]
    return time[num]
# from 0 to 20 seconds with initial velocity of 100 m/s
b = findzero(0.0,20.0,100.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a good approach to solve this sort of problem is to rewrite your equations so that velocity is the independent variable and time and distance are the dependent variables. Then, you simply have to integrate the equations from v=v0 to v=0.

However, in the example you give it is not even necessary to resort to `scipy.integrate` at all. The equations can be easily solved with pencil and paper (separation of variables followed by a standard integral). The result is

> t = (m/(2 Cp)) arctan(v0/2)

where v0 is the initial velocity and the result of arctan must be taken in radians.

For an initial velocity of 100 m/s, the answer is 15.5079899282 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I needed to step away from the computer and look at it with a paper and pencil.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `scipy.optimize.fsolve()` to find the roots of the derivative. Using this, one can work backwards to find the time taken to reach a root.

Comment: I don't think he/she is looking for the time to find the solution, but the time at which the projectile will have v = 0.